# ActionScript 3 : character hit test object with all objects in array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, movieclip

First of all thank you for the attention of anybody reading this question

I'm Indonesian, so apologize if my english was bad.

I'm currently in a school project creating touchscreen Android game using Flash ActionScript 3 or Unity, my current project is made using Flash with ActionScript 3. My current work is a Feeding Frenzy-like game which involves a female scuba diver which will annihilate a fish bomb falling underwater.

I'm trying to make the diver warned for all bombs in the screen. I have a BombsLayer class which will call a RegularBomb Class to fall in random x position. All RegularBomb instance are placed into an Array, then i use for each looping with hitTestObject so if the diver hit the transparent circle inside the movieclip, an exclamation sign will appear and sets the readyToDefuse boolean in diver class to true, and when the diver is away from bomb, the boolean will set to false, and the exclamation sign will dissapear.

My problem is the diver can only interact with the last bomb movieclip instace in the array. when the first bomb child added into the array and the diver reachs it, the exclamation sign would appear, but every time a new bomb instantiated the exclamation sign would disappear and i have to make the diver move to the new bomb instantiated to make the sign appear.

i have read the suggestion on this question : [AS3 - array hit test in 'for each' loop only works properly with last object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700932/as3-array-hit-test-in-for-each-loop-only-works-properly-with-last-object-in) to remove the else statement in the for each loop, but by removing it will make the readyToDefuse remains True and the exclamation sign remains appearing.

i have done a google searching and nothing seems to answer my problem, i have to finish this game for one week until presentation and this had driving me confused for these past days..

here is my complete code for the Bombslayer Class :

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class BombsLayer extends MovieClip{
        public var area:Sprite;
        public var bombs:Array;
        public var bomb:RegularBomb;
        public var bombground:BombGround;
        public var diver:Diver;
        public var warner:BombWarn;

        public function BombsLayer(character:Diver, warn:BombWarn){
            // constructor code
            area = new Sprite();
            area.graphics.beginFill(000000, 0);
            area.graphics.drawRect(0,0,2200,720);
            area.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(area);

            diver = character;
            warner = warn;

            bombs = new Array();
            var newBomb = new RegularBomb(Math.random()*area.width, diver, warner);
            bombs.push(newBomb)
            addChild(newBomb);

            bombground = new BombGround(0, 670, this);
            addChild(bombground);

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBomb);
        }
        function moveBomb(event:Event){
            if(Math.random() <= 0.0005){
                var newBomb = new RegularBomb(Math.random()*area.width, diver, warner);
                bombs.push(newBomb)
                addChild(newBomb);
            }
            for each(var bomb:RegularBomb in bombs){
                bomb.moveDown();
                if(diver.hitTestObject(bomb)){
                    warner.visible = true;
                    diver.readyToDefuse = true;
                }
                else{
                    warner.visible = false;
                    diver.readyToDefuse = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if needed i can upload the complete project too..

All helps would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is wrong. You need to browse through the bombs and find one in contact with diver if any, and work with the only bomb. Otherwise the diver is ready to defuse bomb A but not ready to defuse B, C and D and thus is not ready at all.

```
function moveBomb(event:Event)
{
    var aBomb:RegularBomb;

    if (Math.random() <= 0.0005)
    {
        aBomb = new RegularBomb(Math.random() * area.width, diver, warner);
        bombs.push(aBomb)
        addChild(aBomb);
    }

    for each(aBomb in bombs) aBomb.moveDown();

    // Find bomb in diver's vicinity.
    aBomb = findBomb();

    // The same as "if (aBomb != null)"
    if (aBomb)
    {
        warner.visible = true;
        diver.readyToDefuse = true;
    }
    else
    {
        warner.visible = false;
        diver.readyToDefuse = false;
    }
}

function findBomb():RegularBomb
{
    for each(var aBomb:RegularBomb in bombs)
        if (diver.hitTestObject(aBomb))
            return aBomb;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It works!! actually it's just the beginning, for each bomb reached and the user is holding a defuse button the indicator at the bomb's postition will charge and when it's full, the bomb child will dissapear and the bomb child will be removed from the array..

also, not only bombs, i wanted to do a same interaction with dangerous sea creatures such as sharks, jellyfish, sea snake and puffer fish, but instead of being warned, when the diver hits one of them then the diver's health point will be decreased. do i have to do the same?

by the way Thank you very much!!

Comment: @AzmiFarhan No, the logic of instant hits will be different. Think of it in a general terms. Diver should pick one bomb and get ready to defuse it. Then, **any** dangerous fish would damage the diver instantly, regardless how many fishes that will be.

Comment: so should i use my previous logic then for the fishes?

Comment: or by doing the same i mean by using the same logic you give only with different expression inside if statement that checks the output of the find function?

Comment: @AzmiFarhan Please don't ask me to think for you. I can script all you want to script, of course, but what's the point? It's you who must try to solve it for yourself with as many tries as you could possibly produce on your own, then you will learn something about algorithms.

Comment: Alright then, sorry if i was bothering you, thanks alot for the solutions! :D